# Jenkinsfile on multibranch pipeline cron

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a declarative pipeline for multibranch pipeline job, and I am interested in creating a cron trigger to it.
Currently I already have cron trigger on it for master branch using the following cron string:

```
String cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? '30 23 * * *' : ""
```

I am interested in modifying the cron string so the cron would be triggered when branch name is **master** or if branch name contains the string **release**

I Wondered how can I achieve this
would appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance, Alon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def no_cron = ""
def some_cron = "30 23 * * *" 

CRON_DATA = no_cron

if (BRANCH_NAME == "master" || BRANCH_NAME.contains("release")) {
    CRON_DATA = some_cron 
}

pipeline {
    agent any 

    triggers {
        cron (CRON_DATA)
    }
    ...
}
```